# how to configure slf4j on boneCP

Tags: slf4j, bonecp

BoneCP version=0.7.1

slf4j=1.7.5

Every time when I connect to mysql. It would say

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPConfig).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

But I cann't find any configure Example with boneCP, just give me a example, with explain is good!

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bonecp issue. Did you read your error at all? There's a URL telling you exactly what to do!